# Android Retrofit: How to upload multiple images to server using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

First of all this is not a duplicate question as I tired all the method found on stackoverflow already. I am trying to upload multiple(number changes dynamically) images to server using `Retrofit` library. Currently I am sending two images simultaneously like this

```
ApiUtil.GetRestApi().UploadImages(
                                  new TypedString(userName), 
                                  new TypedFile("image/jpg", files[0]), 
                                  new TypedFile("image/jpg", files[1]), this);
```

And my `Rest Api` looks like this

```
@Multipart
@POST("/image/upload-media/")
void UploadImages(@Part("username") TypedString userName, 
                  @Part("media") TypedFile media1, 
                  @Part("media") TypedFile media2,
                  Callback<MediaUploadResponse> response);
```

This works perfectly fine but I cant go ahead with this as number of images can not be fixed. I found many threads on stackoverflow but I could'nt solve this.
Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use retrofit @PartMap. The API will look like:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/image/upload-media/")
void UploadImages(Map<String,TypedFile> files,
                  Callback<MediaUploadResponse> response);
```

then create the part map using:

```
Map<String, TypedFile> files = new HashMap<String, TypedFile>();
files.put("media1", new TypedFile("image/jpg", files(0)));
files.put("media2", new TypedFile("image/jpg", files(1)));
```

Comment: I will try and let you know the result. Thank you

Comment: `TypedFile` has been removed in retrofit 2.